# How to divide the array based on Input value using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, knn

We have the lets say fold value in KNN is N we need to divide the array in  N equal part and for each iteration of fold value we need to divide the train and test such way that

```
example :
fold is 5
1. In First iteration It Consider last means 5th part as test data and rest train data
2. In Second iteration It Consider second last means 4th part as test data and rest train data
3. In third iteration It Consider third last means 3rd part as test data and rest train data
... so on
5. In  Firth iteration It Consider first means 1st part as test data and rest train data
```

How we can achieve this in Python Can you please explain this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the KFold https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

```
# you can declare number of splits here
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42)
# your model goes here. 
model = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree')
# this will fit your model 5 times and use 1/5 as test data and 4/5 as training data
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train,  y_train, cv=kfold)
```

Comment: you are right but we have to do this operation manually means we are not going to use other then numpy and panda lib.. we are not using any sklearn lib .. can you please help me how to achive this